# Guava Iterables concat implementation does not work with new Iterable API methods added in Java 8?

Tags: java, spring, iterator, guava, iterable

I wanted a simple way to do Iterables concat so I tried Guava Iterables (19 RC1) in my Spring MVC code (Spring 4.2.1).

I have two iterables from Spring Data JPA. e.g.

```
Iterable<Portfolio> result = portfRepository.findBySomeCriteria();
Iterable<Portfolio> result2 = portfRepository.findByOtherCriteria();
```

I then do a concat:

```
Iterable<Portfolio> combined = Iterables.concat(result, result2);
```

However when the combined Iterable is processed by Jackson, it only displayed { empty: false } instead of the array of portfolios.

I looked at Guava's concat implementation. It basically return an ImmutableList of two Iterables, and provided an overridden Iterator that knows how to iterate through first Iterable, then 2nd Iterable.

```
/**
 * Combines two iterables into a single iterable. The returned iterable has an
 * iterator that traverses the elements in {@code a}, followed by the elements
 * in {@code b}. The source iterators are not polled until necessary.
 *
 * <p>The returned iterable's iterator supports {@code remove()} when the
 * corresponding input iterator supports it.
 */
public static <T> Iterable<T> concat(
  Iterable<? extends T> a, Iterable<? extends T> b) {
  return concat(ImmutableList.of(a, b));
}

/**
 * Combines multiple iterables into a single iterable. The returned iterable
 * has an iterator that traverses the elements of each iterable in
 * {@code inputs}. The input iterators are not polled until necessary.
 *
 * <p>The returned iterable's iterator supports {@code remove()} when the
 * corresponding input iterator supports it. The methods of the returned
 * iterable may throw {@code NullPointerException} if any of the input
 * iterators is null.
 */
public static <T> Iterable<T> concat(
  final Iterable<? extends Iterable<? extends T>> inputs) {
  checkNotNull(inputs);
  return new FluentIterable<T>() {
    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
      return Iterators.concat(iterators(inputs));
    }
  };
}
```

The problem is, the Java 8 Iterable API provided new methods:

```
default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)
default Spliterator<T> spliterator()
```

I guess if some code (in this case Spring MVC or Jackson) make use of these methods to loop through the Iterable instead of the iterator method, then the concatenated Guava Iterable which is a List of Iterables will not work probably. Can someone confirm this? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this easy to test by yourself?

Comment: The fact that the `Iterable` is rendered as `{"empty": false}` by Jackson shows that Jackson doesn't support `Iterable`s out of the box, at least in the version you're using: it doesn't know it's supposed to iterate on it, so it just rendered the only thing that looks like a property, which is the `isEmpty()` method.

Comment: Also, "default methods" like `forEach()` are methods added to an existing interface in Java 8 **with a default implementation** (hence the name) to provide backward compatibility, so they'll work for any `Iterable` in this case.

Comment: @FrankPavageau If I just return one Iterable (say result) Jackson can convert it correctly. It has no problem with that. As I stated in my post above, I think it is due to Guava implements an Iterable as a ImmutableList of Iterables.

Comment: Nope, default methods don't work like that: they provide the implementation of new methods for all implementers of the interface, they cannot "not work" (throwing an exception could be an acceptable form of "working", but it's not the case here). It probably works when you return one `Iterable` because the actual type of that object is something known to Jackson, like an `ArrayList`. Guava implements `concat()` with an anonymous `FluentIterable` using an `ImmutableList`, not an `ImmutableList` itself, so it's really just an `Iterable` and not actually a subclass of `Collection`.

Comment: Jackson knows how to serialize/deserialize collections, not iterables. Either add Jackson's support jar for Guava or work with collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the following dependency:

[This adds support for Guava specific datatypes.](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-guava)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-guava</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You probably will need the [JDK8 datatypes](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8) as well at some point.